# ASM program returns 1 instead of intended value WSL

Tags: assembly, return-value, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Aperrently, 32-bit system calls are not supported under WSL

Thank you Timothy Baldwin!
I made a simple program to return the highest element of an array, but `$ echo $?` echos 1, instead of 222
I am using as GNU assembler

```
/*
%edi will hold the current position in the list.
%ebx will hold the current highest value in the list.
%eax will hold the current element being examined
*/

# data_items - contains the item data. A 0 is used
# to terminate the data

.section .data

data_items: #These are the data items
.long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0


.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
  movl $0, %edi                  # zero into index register 
  movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax #load the first bit
  movl %eax, %ebx                # since this is the first item, %eax is the biggest

start_loop:                      # start loop 
  cmpl $0, %eax                      # check if element==0
  je loop_exit                   
  incl %edi                      # load next element
  movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
  cmpl %eax, %ebx                # compare value
  jle start_loop                 # jump to beginning if element is not the largest


  movl %eax, %ebx                # move the value as the largest

  jmp start_loop                 # go to beginning

  loop_exit:
    movl $1, %eax                # exit

  int $0x80                      #call kernel
```

Comment: AT&T syntax is the other way round. Therefore, change `cmpl %eax, %ebx ` to `cmpl %ebx, %eax`.

Comment: Don't edit your question to say "Solved", that's not how we do things on Stack Overflow.  Click the checkbox under an answer to mark it accepted.  (If there are no existing answers which contain the actual solution, write an answer.  Do not edit the answer into the question.  If you do that, it's not a question anymore.)

Comment: I'm surprised this ran at all under WSL, unless you built a 64-bit executable out of this source that looks like it's written for 32-bit mode (32-bit addressing modes as well as 32-bit system calls.)  Was there any error message from the shell, like segmentation fault?

Comment: no there wasn't

Comment: @Peter Cordes none of the answers solved it, it was a comment

Comment: Someone may argue this isn't a duplicate of the one I have identified. Not an exact duplicate by any means, but the duplicate and the answer does capture the essence of the issue - WSL won't run 32-bit executables. If you assemble 32-bit code as 64-bit code using `int 0x80` 32-bit system call interface that isn't supported either. You'll need to write your code as 64-bit and use the 64-bit `syscall` interface for it to work under WSL.

Comment: can you please provide a link

Comment: Since I marked it as a duplicate the duplicate link is now above your question.

Comment: @Screwballer: like I said in my comment, if none of the *answers* have the answer, then write one yourself.  (Even if you repeat what was said in comments).  Remember, this is for the benefit of future readers who have the same problem: we want the correct answer to be there at the top, not buried in with other comments.  You don't need to do anything in this case because there's already another question where that was the answer, so \@MichaelPetch marked the question as a duplicate.

Comment: i dont have enough rep

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly correct, but the error is caused by a wrong `Jcc` instruction. So change the line

```
jle start_loop   # jump to beginning if element is not the largest
```

to the right `Jcc` instruction

```
jge start_loop   # jump to beginning if element is not the largest
```

and your code works as expected.

Comment: I tried that but it did not solve the return value issue, it still returns 1 although when I used stdout on the value it was correct so thanks

Comment: @Screwballer: Now I do understand better. I had problems with the return value as well. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for that, too.

Comment: I think i found the problem, i am using linux subsystem for linux, and a return value of 0 translates to 1 in the logging

Comment: Linux subsystem for Windows does not support 32 bit system calls so your program crashes.

Comment: <=========Redacted==========>

Comment: @Timothy Baldwin thank you